# boto - copy snapshot to another region

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, snapshot

Any ideas on how to easily copy a snapshot to another region with boto?

You can easily do it through the management console - right clicking the snapshot, then "copy", then choosing your preferable region.

I hoped to have something similar with boto but couldn't find any.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `copy_snapshot()` method in the EC2 module to copy snapshots within a region or between regions.  For example, if you had an existing snapshot in `us-east-1` and you wanted to copy it to `us-west-2` you could do this:

```
import boto.ec2

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-west-2')
conn.copy_snapshot(source_region='us-east-1', source_snap_id='snap-12345678',
                   description='My new copy')
```

see: [boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.copy_snapshot](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.copy_snapshot)

Comment: Thanks garnaat and andpei, I didn't think of looking there

Answer (score 1):

Faced a bug with boto3, as the destination region parameter gets skipped and it copies snapshots to same region itself.

[EC2 Copy Snapshot Ignoring Destination Region Parameter](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/886)

For this to work, lambda function can be created in destination region, but set the region parameter in the code to the source region where you have the snasphots.

```
region = 'eu-central-1'
ec = boto3.client('ec2',region_name=region)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response=ec.copy_snapshot(SourceSnapshotId='snap-082*********4aac2',
                     SourceRegion=region,
                     DestinationRegion='eu-west-1',
                     Description='copied from Frankfurt')
    print (response)
```

Here, the lambda function is created in eu-west-1(Ireland), and SourceSnapshotId is a snap Id from eu-central-1(Frankfurt)